# Waveforms and buckling modes

Tags: material-science, elasticity, differential-equations

Can anything be said about the expected shape of a specific buckling mode? Or more precisely, is is true for example that for the first buckling mode the second derivative of lateral deflection w.r.t the length $d^2w / dx^2$ maintains its sign over the whole span $L$?

If yes, how can one show that mathematically? 
For a beam, one can easily work it out from $w(x) = A\sin(n\pi x/L)$ with $n=1$, but how about a plate for example?

Can any generalisation be made?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i was looking for [in this MIT paper](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-080j-structural-mechanics-fall-2013/course-notes/MIT2_080JF13_Lecture11.pdf). The out-of-plane deflection equation that satisfies the governing differential equation is of the form:

$w(x, y)=sin(\frac{mπx}{a})sin(\frac{nπy}{b})$

with *a* & *b* being the plate *length* and *width* respectively.

The equation for the critical load (11.4 in the aforementioned paper) has a minimum when ***n=1*** (only a half-wave in the direction perpendicular to the load application direction) but the for the value of ***m***, it depends on the ***a/b*** ratio as figure 11.2 beautifully demonstrates. *To put it simply, the bigger the ratio, the more waves it can fit on its length as intuitively assumed.*

Suprisingly and almost fascinatingly the ratios for which the number of **halfwaves** increases by 1 is:

- $\sqrt{2}$ from 1 to 2
- $\sqrt{6}$ from 2 to 3
- $\sqrt{12}$ from 3 to 4
- $\sqrt{20}$ from 4 to 5 and so on..